# How to verify sorting in selenium + java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, automation

[image]

I need to test that items sorted by price:

```
        List<WebElement> elements2 = driver.findElements(By.className("price"));
    for (WebElement element : elements2) {
        System.out.println(element.getText());
    }
```

Here I collected all the values in the list, now I need to remove "грн" and convert values to int, and then somehow verify that they are sorted how it should be, but I have no idea how to do it :(

I will be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Integer> price = (List<Integer>) elements2.stream().map(c -> {
        WebElement a = (WebElement) c;
                       //you can add getText() also
        String value = a.getAttribute("textContent");

        int pricelocal = Integer.parseInt(value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));

        return pricelocal;

    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(price);
```

Above line of code will create a list containing only prices

Now now copy it a temp array , sort the temp array and verify if sorted temp array and initial array are equal :

```
    List<Integer> priceTemp = new ArrayList<Integer>(price);
    Collections.sort(priceTemp, Collections.reverseOrder()); 
            
    System.out.println(priceTemp.equals(price));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to verify the prices are sorted by converting it to integer.
sorted() - ascending order
sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) - descendinng order

```
List<Integer> priceValues = elements2.stream()
                .map(a->Integer.parseInt(a.getText().replaceAll("[^0-9 ]+", "")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        boolean isSorted = priceValues.equals(priceValues.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```